# Unsubscribe from GeoQuery.onSnapshot on document deletion

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, geofirestore

I have an `onWrite` Cloud Function

```
exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document("test/{docId}").onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    return await test(change);
});
```

At the topmost of `test` i have a variable `listener`, then i have two conditions that checks whether a document was just created or deleted. Inside the first `if` block i assign `...onSnapshot(...)` to `listener` then inside the second `if` block i call `listener()` to unsubscribe from the `GeoQuery.onSnapshot` subscription made in the first `if` block, in other words, when a document is created `listener` is assigned to `...onSnapshot(...)`. Subsequently when that same document is deleted, i unsubscribe from the previous onSnapshot subscription

```
const test = async (change) => {
  let listener;

  if (!change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
    // document created, subscribe
    listener = GeoFirestore.collection(...)
        .where("category", "==", ...)
        .near({ center: ..., radius: ... })
        .onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {...}, (error) => {...});
  }

  if (change.before.exists && !change.after.exists) {
    // document deleted, unsubscribe
    listener();
  }
```

The problem is i am getting an error when the second `if` block gets triggerred

> TypeError: listener is not a function

This Cloud Function is in such a way that the first if block will always get called before the second if block (obviously a document can get deleted only after it is created) and according to the [Geofirestore docs](https://geofirestore.com/)

> onSnapshot
>
> ```
> get onSnapshot(): (onNext: (snapshot: GeoQuerySnapshot) =>
> void, onError?: (error: Error) => void) => () => void
> ```
>
> Defined in src/GeoQuery.ts:74
>
> Attaches a listener for GeoQuerySnapshot events. Returns
>
> ```
> (onNext: (snapshot: GeoQuerySnapshot) => void, onError?:
> (error: Error) => void) => () => void
> ```
>
> An unsubscribe function that can be called to cancel the snapshot
> listener.

I don't see what i seem to be doing wrong here. I need some help

Comment: In a Cloud Function you usually read Firestore documents/collections once with the get() method and do not set a listener. As a matter of fact Cloud Functions are initially designed to execute rather short actions and should preferably not be kept idle with a listener. You should probably re-think your architecture. Maybe you could describe in detail your functional requirement and we could propose other approaches.

Comment: Hello @RenaudTarnec, my cloud function is supposed to be triggered when a new document is created in my `test` collection. Its duty is to watch another collection for nearby documents (hence my use of the geofirestore library). If any is found it should copy the content of that document to a document in this `test` collection and then delete the document from the other collection.

Comment: When this happens a pop up will be shown on the client to either accept or deny. If the client denies, then content that was just copied to a document in this `test` collection should be reversed back to the other collection. The action should continue to repeat itself until a client corresponding to a document owner in the other collection accepts.

Comment: But if the client accepts then this document in the `test` collection, its content together with the content copied from the other document in the other collection should be copied to a new document in a third collection and subsequently the document in this `test` collection should get deleted. Hence i need this listener to keep running while this document in the `test` collection still exists. The thing is that this stuff actually works fine but when i try to cancel the listener when the document in this `test` document gets deleted i get this error

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations. Are you sure you need a Cloud Function to implement this fucntion. You may set the listener directly from the front-end. If you nned to use a Cloud Function (e.g. because you don't want to give full read access to your collection) and you want to regularly check if one or more docs are nearby a specific doc, I would use a Scheduled Cloud Function instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RenaudTarnec . I'll consider it